# Opening an eclipse project through command prompt or batch file

Tags: eclipse, command-line, selenium-rc

I am building an application that is for testing using Selenium Java tool.
Is there any way to open an existing eclipse project from the command line or through a batch file so that I can allow the users to select the testproject which is in Java with just a click of a button?

I found that this command if for building a project

```
eclipsec.exe -noSplash -data "D:\Source\MyProject\workspace" -application org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild
```

But I couldn't find one for opening one.

Answer (score 0):

If you omit `-application` and simply run `eclipse.exe -data "D:\Source\MyProject\workspace"`, then your workspace will be opened. If you have only one project there then issue is resolved. If not, you can easily create new workspace with a link to your existing project.