# Building an Android Project from Command Line with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, command-line, build

I created a "Hello World" Android Project in Eclipse (Indigo) on Windows 7 64-bit. It's using Android SDK 1.6.

It builds from the IDE without any problems.

Now I want to build it from the command line.
I found this question: [Opening an eclipse project through command prompt or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5177748/673064)
and [Headless Building with APT in Eclipse](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/eclipse_documentation/eclipse_jdt_plug-in_developer_guide/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/eclipse_jdt_plugin_jdt_apt_building_with_apt.htm), so I ran this:

```
C:\inst\Android\eclipse>eclipsec.exe -data "C:\eclipsewsTest1" -application org.
eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild
```

What I'm getting is the following:

```
Building workspace
Building '/And1'
Invoking builder on '/And1'.
Invoking builder on '/And1'.
Invoking 'Java Builder' on '/And1'.
Cleaning output folder for And1
Build done
Invoking builder on '/And1'.
```

and then a dialog shows this message:

```
An error has occurred. See the log file C:\eclipsewsTest1\.metadata\.log
```

This log file contains something like this:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20110909-1335
java.version=1.7.0_01
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -application org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -data C:\eclipsewsTest1 -application org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2011-12-09 10:50:35.233
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-12-09 10:50:35.553
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms (351).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.DdmsPlugin.start() of bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.
```

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: Just curious to know why you are doing it this way, rather than using something like maven as your build system

Comment: user859955, is Maven generally the way people would use to automate Android project builds? Is calling eclipsec from a script not recommended?

Comment: Did you find a solution to triggering an Eclipse build? I am trying to do the same thing at the moment.

Answer (score 17):

```
# 1. go into you Eclipse project
cd "C:\Users\username\workspace\app"

# 2. create build files (only first time)
"C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\android.bat" update project --path .

# 3. Set Java JDK Path
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25

# 4. Build with "ant debug"
"C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v20120321-1730\bin\ant" debug

# 5. Deploy (and replace existing with -r)
"C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" 
   install -r "C:\Users\username\workspace\app\bin\appActivity-debug.apk"

# 6. Run it. Look up package and activity name in `AndroidManifest.xml`
"C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" 
   shell am start -n <your_package>/<activity_android:name>

# 7. View log.
"C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" logcat
```

Also see [this blog](http://blog.standalonecode.com/?p=269) and [Android help](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html#DebugMode).

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously recommend to use the standard correct way to build using a build tool like ant.
ADT provides pretty good support for ant and generates the build script for you using your eclipse project itself. So the overall effort is pretty minimal and is fast. You can find how to do this here:

http://pissedoff-techie.blogspot.in/2014/07/how-to-build-android-project-in-eclipse.html